# HTML - A cleaner way to use select option

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have an issue where by I need a nicer-looking way to use select option that caters to Countries (240+ countries). I plan to use `select2` to enhance the searching experience.
Now, a regular select-option with some values in it will just look like this

```
<select>
  <option value=..></option>
<select>
```

But in the case of selecting Nationality, there are 240+ countries and suddenly a nice piece of code like this will look terrible.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="alias" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Alias</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="alias" placeholder="Employee alias">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 control-label">DoB</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="dob" placeholder="Date of birth">
    </div>
</div>
<! 240++ lines worth of options->
```

Any inputs?

Comment: Why don't you store details of countries in JSON file or XML or DB. Then fetch all data using just one loop?

Comment: Do you have a specific quesion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery` and `Array()` for this kind of things someway. Just put the countries you want to be shown in `var countries` which is array. But it will be easier to make .cvs file that has all the country names on the database and call them from it. Anyways this JQuery source might help for your question.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var countries = new Array();
 /* here you put all the countries you want in array */
 countries = ["Korea", "USA", "China", "India", "etc"];
 
 for(i = 0;i < countries.length;i++) {
  $("#select2").append("<option value='"+countries[i]+"'>"+countries[i]+"</option>");
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="alias" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Alias</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="alias" placeholder="Employee alias">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 control-label">DoB</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="dob" placeholder="Date of birth">
    </div>
</div>

<!--  240++ lines worth of options -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="select2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <!-- this is where countries enters -->
     <select name="" id="select2">
     </select>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```